# Create tree like structure on flat ag-grid table without using tree structure of ag-grid

Tags: vue.js, tree, treeview, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I have some heirachical data I don't want to display using a tree data structure offered by ag-grid, but on the flat table itself using cell-renderer want to showcase it as a tree.
I am able to mange the indentation as per hierarchy but not able to make the adjust the vertical and horizontal lines .
[image]

Desired structure like,
[image]

cell renderer code is as below,

```
      <template>
      <div class="hierarchical-tree-cell">
        <div class="indentation" :style="{ width: indentationWidth }">
          <div class="vertical-line"></div>
          <div class="dotted-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tree-content">
          {{ hierarchy[level] }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup>
    import { computed } from "vue";
    const props = defineProps({ params: { type: Object, default: () => ({}) } });
    
    const hierarchy = props.params.data.hierarchy;
    const level = hierarchy.length - 1;
    
    const indentationWidth = computed(() => {
      return `${level * 20}px`; // Adjust the multiplier as needed
    });
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    .hierarchical-tree-cell {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

.tree-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indentation {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.vertical-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.dotted-line {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
  border-left: 1px dotted #ccc;
}/
</style>
```

and json is like ,

```
[
  {
    "AffectedPart": "91422146",
    "owner": "dsotest27.im",
    "physicalid": "B1009056833D00009FC7D458BE2A0400",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146"
    ],
    "description": "test",
    "type": "Formulation Part",
    "Title": "test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.28416.41775",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "91422146-001",
    "owner": "dsotest27.im",
    "physicalid": "B1009056833D0000BCC7D458F5510B00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001"
    ],
    "description": "test",
    "type": "Formulation Process",
    "Title": "test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Formulation Process",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.28416.57429",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "FMPHASE-00006046",
    "owner": "dsotest27.im",
    "physicalid": "B1009056833D0000F3CAD4581FD90200",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006046"
    ],
    "description": "",
    "type": "Formulation Phase",
    "Title": "Form_Phase",
    "revision": "A",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Formulation Phase",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.62720.6296",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "40000003",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "B100905683400000726D4058A8B80800",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006046",
      "40000003"
    ],
    "description": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.56832.47789",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "99274215",
    "ats_Title": "99274215",
    "ats_Revision": "-",
    "ats_MinPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "-",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "ats_MaxPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "-",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "-",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "ats_DryPer": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "-",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMin": "-",
    "QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "MaxPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMax": "-",
    "TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "-",
    "TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "DryPer": "-",
    "ProcessingNote": "-"
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "40000003",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "B100905683400000726D4058A8B80800",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006046",
      "40000003"
    ],
    "description": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.56832.47789",
    "ats_Operation": "-",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "91422146",
    "ats_Title": "91422146",
    "ats_Revision": "-",
    "ats_MinPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "-",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "ats_MaxPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "-",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "-",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "ats_DryPer": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "-",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMin": "-",
    "QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "MaxPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMax": "-",
    "TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "-",
    "TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "DryPer": "-",
    "ProcessingNote": "-"
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "40000003",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "B100905683400000726D4058A8B80800",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006046",
      "90643235"
    ],
    "description": "BAT4 NAR Security Case 2",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "PBAT4 NAR Security Case 2",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.2624.24188",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "FMPHASE-00194174",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "9C2E94561A510000DD7AB95D42090D00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001",
      "FMPHASE-00194174"
    ],
    "description": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.54947.40554",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "-",
    "ats_MinPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "-",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "ats_MaxPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "-",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "-",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "ats_DryPer": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "-",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMin": "-",
    "QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "MaxPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMax": "-",
    "TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "-",
    "TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "DryPer": "-",
    "ProcessingNote": "-"
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "40000060",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "9C2E94561A510000DD7AB95D42090D00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91422146",
      "91422146-001",
      "FMPHASE-00194174",
      "40000060"
    ],
    "description": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.54947.40554",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "-",
    "ats_MinPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "-",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "ats_MaxPer": "-",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "-",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "-",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "ats_DryPer": "-",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "-",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMin": "-",
    "QuantityWetPer": "-",
    "MaxPer": "-",
    "WetWeightMax": "-",
    "TargetWetWeight": "-",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "-",
    "TargetDryWeight": "-",
    "DryPer": "-",
    "ProcessingNote": "-"
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "91010208",
    "owner": "dsotest30.im",
    "physicalid": "0808B16BE11E00003450855BE8410D00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010208"
    ],
    "description": "Test many-many and DSM structure from Reform",
    "type": "Formulation Part",
    "Title": "R&D",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.11265.2077",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "91010208-001",
    "owner": "dsotest30.im",
    "physicalid": "0808B16BE11E00003550855B40690000",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010208",
      "91010208-001"
    ],
    "description": "Test many-many and DSM structure from Reform",
    "type": "Formulation Process",
    "Title": "R&D",
    "revision": "1",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Formulation Process",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.11265.4893",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "FMPHASE-00006129",
    "owner": "dsotest30.im",
    "physicalid": "0808B16BE11E00007250855B2E9B0500",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010208",
      "91010208-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006129"
    ],
    "description": "",
    "type": "Formulation Phase",
    "Title": "Test",
    "revision": "A",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Formulation Phase",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.56832.40343",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "40000003",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "B100905683400000726D4058A8B80800",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010208",
      "91010208-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006129",
      "40000003"
    ],
    "description": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.56832.47789",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "91010404",
    "owner": "dsotest27.im",
    "physicalid": "0808B16B28040000C8CF8E5B051D0B00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010404"
    ],
    "description": "testing decimals",
    "type": "Formulation Part",
    "Title": "Testing decimals",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.63488.55019",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "91010404-001",
    "owner": "dsotest27.im",
    "physicalid": "0808B16B28040000C8CF8E5BA9270E00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010404",
      "91010404-001"
    ],
    "description": "testing decimals",
    "type": "Formulation Process",
    "Title": "Testing decimals",
    "revision": "1",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Formulation Process",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.63488.58917",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "FMPHASE-00006214",
    "owner": "dsotest27.im",
    "physicalid": "0808B16B28040000E3CF8E5B255C0A00",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010404",
      "91010404-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006214"
    ],
    "description": "",
    "type": "Formulation Phase",
    "Title": "TEST123",
    "revision": "A",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Formulation Phase",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.13568.3016",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "Operation": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  },
  {
    "AffectedPart": "40000003",
    "owner": "dsotest29.im",
    "physicalid": "B100905683400000726D4058A8B80800",
    "hierarchy": [
      "91010404",
      "91010404-001",
      "FMPHASE-00006214",
      "40000003"
    ],
    "description": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "Operation": "BOM",
    "type": "pgRawMaterial",
    "Title": "Pinar RMP Test",
    "revision": "001",
    "current": "Preliminary",
    "displayType": "Raw Material IRMS",
    "Primary": "-",
    "id": "20336.41905.56832.47789",
    "ats_Operation": "",
    "ats_ReplacementRawMaterialIntermediate": "",
    "ats_Title": "",
    "ats_Revision": "",
    "ats_MinPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMin": "",
    "ats_QuantityWetPer": "",
    "ats_MaxPer": "",
    "ats_WetWeightMax": "",
    "ats_TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ats_ProcessingLoss": "",
    "ats_TargetDryWeight": "",
    "ats_DryPer": "",
    "ats_ProcessingNote": "",
    "PrimaryQuantity": 0,
    "SubstituteQuantity": 0,
    "MinPer": "",
    "WetWeightMin": "",
    "QuantityWetPer": "",
    "MaxPer": "",
    "WetWeightMax": "",
    "TargetWetWeight": "",
    "ProcessingLossPer": "",
    "TargetDryWeight": "",
    "DryPer": "",
    "ProcessingNote": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: please trim down the example data to a minimal example that demonstrates your issue

Comment: Your JSON data doesn't seem to correspond to the screenshot, would be much easier for someone to help you if you adjusted that to match, and trim while you're at it, as requested above.